# How can I populate XML with Data in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a some XML like below sample which i need to add values/data for the elements. What is the best way to do so short of building a string like

```
mystr += "<HDR>" & vbCrLf
mystr += "<MESSAGE_ID>" & trim(myMessageID) & "</MESSAGE_ID>" & vbCrLf
mystr +=  .... and so on
```

This is what my XML looks like just for reference

```
<HDR>
    <MESSAGE_ID></MESSAGE_ID>
    <CCNA></CCNA>
    <MSG_TIMESTAMP></MSG_TIMESTAMP>
    <TXNUM></TXNUM>
    <TXTYP></TXTYP>
    <TXACT></TXACT>
    <RVER></RVER>
    <TEST_PROD_INDICATOR></TEST_PROD_INDICATOR>
</HDR>
```

Comment: Try XmlWriter. Or Linq to XML.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest to use way is to use Linq to XML which offers `XElement` to to represent elements. The elements can be nested to create structures in code that look very similiar to what you have as an XML Document.
Here is a simple example using your sample data with nested elements and the message id set for demonstration purposes.

```
Sub Main
    Dim hdr = New XElement("HDR", 
                New XElement("MESSAGE_ID", 999999),
                New XElement("CCNA"), 
                New XElement("MSG_TIMESTAMP"),
                New XElement("TXNUM"), 
                New XElement("TXTYP"), 
                New XElement("TXACT"), 
                New XElement("RVER"),
                New XElement("TEST_PROD_INDICATOR")
           )
    Console.WriteLine(hdr.ToString())
End Sub
```

The three most important classes are [XDocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocument?view=netframework-4.7.1), [XElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement?view=netframework-4.7.1) and [XAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xattribute?view=netframework-4.7.1).